# Concatenate n objects in a list in R

Tags: r

This seems like it should be a simple task, but I've been trying for hours with no luck. I think I can explain my problem without providing example data.

I am trying to concatenate objects in a list into a single object. For example, I have a series of stars objects in a list called `ncdf` from which I can pull elements in the basic way:

`ncdf[[1]]` will extract the first element
`ncdf[[2]]` will extract the second, and so forth.

Using stars, I am able to combine them into a single object using the base concatenate function `c()`. I can get the result I want manually by coding like so: `y <- c(ncdf[[1]], ncdf[[2]])`

My question is, I want to be able to concatenate n objects in my list. So if my list is comprised of 1000 stars objects, I obviously would not write `y <- c(ncdf[[1]], ncdf[[2]],...,ncdf[[1000]]` all the way to 1000. Is there a loop or some other way I could combine n list items into a single object??

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to do

```
Reduce(c, ncdf)
```

Comment: Ugh, so simple!! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To add onto the provided answers, you can also use:

```
unlist(ncdf)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do.call`:

```
do.call('c', ncdf)
```